Batch_size vs LSTM neurons in the hidden layer
I found a very good explanation about iterations vs batch_size posted here many years ago from @Djib2011. My dubt is now about this question. If a batch_size numbers (5) of rows (1-5) have passed to five lstm cell (1-5) for five gradient process iterations (hipothesi with parallel iterations) and the second batch_ size numbers of row (6-10) have passed to others five lstm cells(6-10) what happened in a hidden layer with 32 lstm cells since 32 isn't divisible for 5?? Thanks
